# Testing if two sprite overlap while using matrices

Tags: python, matrix, pygame, collision-detection, overlap

Right now, I have a ball that moves around the screen in a random diagonal direction and bounces off the wall when it collides with it.

**What I want to do:**
If the ball goes over a cell/box in the grid, have the cell/box turn red and then keep changing colors until the amount of times that specific spot is 10. If the value is equal to 10, the program ends.

Let me give you a scenario: let's say I have a 3x3 grid and each cell in that grid has a value of 0. Every time the ball goes over a cell, that value goes up by one until it hits 3. Every time the value goes up, the color for that cell changes. 0=white, 1=red, 2=green, and 3=blue. That's what I wanted the output to be.

**What I have so far:**
The entire screen turns red instead of just the individual cell.
I am just testing it for one color at the moment, but then want to add a multitude of colors.

```py
for row in range(GRIDY):
    for column in range(GRIDX):
        rect = [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN, (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN, WIDTH, HEIGHT]
        color = WHITE
        if GRIDY or GRIDX == 1:
            color = RED
        pg.draw.rect(screen, color, rect)
```

Here's the rest of the code for reference:

```py
import sys
import math
from random import randrange
import pygame as pg

# define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

# define measurements
WIDTH, HEIGHT, MARGIN = 10, 10, 1
GRIDX, GRIDY = 91, 36

class GridObject(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, grid, *groups):
        super().__init__(groups)

        # create image from grid
        self.grid = grid
        self.gridsize = (len(grid[0]), len(grid))
        imgsize = self.gridsize[0]*(WIDTH+MARGIN), self.gridsize[1]*(HEIGHT+MARGIN)
        self.image = pg.Surface(imgsize, flags=pg.SRCALPHA)
        self.image.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))
        col = (235, 175, 76)
        for c in range(self.gridsize[0]):
            for r in range(self.gridsize[1]):
                if self.grid[r][c] == 1:
                    rect = [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * c + MARGIN, (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * r + MARGIN, WIDTH, HEIGHT]
                    pg.draw.rect(self.image, col, rect)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.vel = pg.math.Vector2(8, 0).rotate(randrange(360))
        self.pos = pg.math.Vector2(pos)


    def update(self, boundrect):
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        if self.rect.left <= boundrect.left or self.rect.right >= boundrect.right:
            self.vel.x *= -1                            
        if self.rect.top <= boundrect.top or self.rect.bottom >= boundrect.bottom:
            self.vel.y *= -1     
        # align rect to grid
        gridpos = round(self.rect.x / (WIDTH+MARGIN)), round(self.rect.y / (HEIGHT+MARGIN))
        self.rect.topleft = gridpos[0] * (WIDTH+MARGIN), gridpos[1] * (HEIGHT+MARGIN)

ballGrid = [[0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]]

def main():
    #overlap = False
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((GRIDX * (WIDTH+MARGIN) + MARGIN, GRIDY * (HEIGHT+MARGIN)))
    # Set title of screen
    pg.display.set_caption("Ball With Grid")
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    sprite_group = pg.sprite.Group()
    ball = GridObject((495, 193), ballGrid, sprite_group)
    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
                # Used to track the grid coordinates
                if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    # Get the position is screen is clicked
                    pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
                    # Change the x/y screen coordinates to grid coordinates
                    column = pos[0] // (WIDTH + MARGIN)
                    row = pos[1] // (HEIGHT + MARGIN)
                    # Set that location to one
                    grid[row][column] = 1
                    print("Click ", pos, "Grid coordinates: ", row, column)


        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        # Draw the grid and add values to the cells
        for row in range(GRIDY):
            for column in range(GRIDX):
                rect = [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN, (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN, WIDTH, HEIGHT]
                color = WHITE
                if GRIDY or GRIDX == 1:
                    color = RED
                pg.draw.rect(screen, color, rect)

        sprite_group.update(screen.get_rect())
        sprite_group.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

*btw if this looks similar, my other account posted this question:* [Using a matrix as a sprite and testing if two sprites overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60387917/using-a-matrix-as-a-sprite-and-testing-if-two-sprites-overlap)

Link to the images:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYZdA.jpg

Comment: I must have unchecked by accident. It is checked now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> let's say I have a 3x3 grid and each cell in that grid has a value of 0. Every time the ball goes over a cell, that value goes up by one until it hits 3. Every time the value goes up, the color for that cell changes. 0=white, 1=red, 2=green, and 3=blue. That's what I wanted the output to be.

You have how often the ball is on a cell, for each cell. Since the ball covers more than 1 cell (the size of the ball is greater than 1 cell), the cell counter would be incremented multiple times in consecutive frames, when the ball rolls over the cell.
So you have to ensure that a ball has left a cell, before its counter is allowed to be incremented again.

Create a 2 dimensional array (nested list) of integral values, initialized by 0 with the size of the field. The filed sores the hit counters for the cells. Furthermore, create a list (`hitList`) which stores the indices of the cells which have been hit in a frame.

```py
hitGrid = [[0 for i in range(GRIDX)] for j in range(GRIDY)]
hitList = []
```

The grid (`hitGrid`) and the list (`hitList`) have to be passed to the `update` method of the class `GridObject`. If the ball touches a field and the field was not touched in the previous frame, then the corresponding entry in the gird is has to be incremented. Further more the function can set a global variable `max_hit`, wiht the highest fit count in the current frame:

```py
class GridObject(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def update(self, boundrect, gridHit):
        # [...]

        # increment touched filed
        global max_hit
        max_hit = 0
        oldHitList = hitList[:]
        hitList.clear()
        for c in range(self.gridsize[0]):
            for r in range(self.gridsize[1]):
                p = gridpos[1] + r, gridpos[0] + c
                if p in oldHitList:
                    hitList.append(p)
                elif self.grid[r][c] == 1:
                    if p[0] < len(hitGrid) and p[1] < len(hitGrid[p[0]]):
                        hitList.append(p)
                        if p not in oldHitList:
                            hitGrid[p[0]][p[1]] +=1
                            max_hit = max(max_hit, hitGrid[p[0]][p[1]])
```

Evaluate `max_hit` after invoke `update` to the `GridObject` obejcts:

```py
sprite_group.update(screen.get_rect(), hitGrid, hitList)
if max_hit >= 4:
    print("game over")
    done = True
```

Tint the color of a field dependent on the value in `gridHit`:

```py
for row in range(GRIDY):
    for column in range(GRIDX):
        rect = [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN, (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN, WIDTH, HEIGHT]
        colorlist = [WHITE, RED, GREEN, BLUE]
        color = colorlist[min(len(colorlist)-1, hitGrid[row][column])]
        pg.draw.rect(screen, color, rect)
```

See the example:

[image]

```py
from random import randrange
import pygame as pg

# define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

# define measurements
WIDTH, HEIGHT, MARGIN = 10, 10, 1
GRIDX, GRIDY = 36, 36

class GridObject(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, grid, *groups):
        super().__init__(groups)

        # create image from grid
        self.grid = grid
        self.gridsize = (len(grid[0]), len(grid))
        imgsize = self.gridsize[0]*(WIDTH+MARGIN), self.gridsize[1]*(HEIGHT+MARGIN)
        self.image = pg.Surface(imgsize, flags=pg.SRCALPHA)
        self.image.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))
        col = (235, 175, 76)
        for c in range(self.gridsize[0]):
            for r in range(self.gridsize[1]):
                if self.grid[r][c] == 1:
                    rect = [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * c + MARGIN, (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * r + MARGIN, WIDTH, HEIGHT]
                    pg.draw.rect(self.image, col, rect)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.vel = pg.math.Vector2(8, 0).rotate(randrange(360))
        self.pos = pg.math.Vector2(pos)


    def update(self, boundrect, hitGrid, hitList):
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        if self.rect.left <= boundrect.left or self.rect.right >= boundrect.right:
            self.vel.x *= -1                            
        if self.rect.top <= boundrect.top or self.rect.bottom >= boundrect.bottom:
            self.vel.y *= -1     
        # align rect to grid
        gridpos = round(self.rect.x / (WIDTH+MARGIN)), round(self.rect.y / (HEIGHT+MARGIN))
        self.rect.topleft = gridpos[0] * (WIDTH+MARGIN), gridpos[1] * (HEIGHT+MARGIN)

        # increment touched filed
        global max_hit
        max_hit = 0
        oldHitList = hitList[:]
        hitList.clear()
        for c in range(self.gridsize[0]):
            for r in range(self.gridsize[1]):
                p = gridpos[1] + r, gridpos[0] + c
                if p in oldHitList:
                    hitList.append(p)
                elif self.grid[r][c] == 1:
                    if p[0] < len(hitGrid) and p[1] < len(hitGrid[p[0]]):
                        hitList.append(p)
                        if p not in oldHitList:
                            hitGrid[p[0]][p[1]] +=1
                            max_hit = max(max_hit, hitGrid[p[0]][p[1]])

ballGrid = [[0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]]

def main():
    #overlap = False
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((GRIDX * (WIDTH+MARGIN) + MARGIN, GRIDY * (HEIGHT+MARGIN)))
    # Set title of screen
    pg.display.set_caption("Ball With Grid")
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    sprite_group = pg.sprite.Group()
    ball = GridObject((screen.get_width()//2, screen.get_height()//2), ballGrid, sprite_group)
    hitGrid = [[0 for i in range(GRIDX)] for j in range(GRIDY)]
    hitList = []
    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN and event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                hitGrid = [[0 for i in range(GRIDX)] for j in range(GRIDY)] 

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        # Draw the grid and add values to the cells
        for row in range(GRIDY):
            for column in range(GRIDX):
                rect = [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN, (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN, WIDTH, HEIGHT]
                colorlist = [WHITE, RED, GREEN, BLUE]
                color = colorlist[min(len(colorlist)-1, hitGrid[row][column])]
                pg.draw.rect(screen, color, rect)

        sprite_group.update(screen.get_rect(), hitGrid, hitList)
        if max_hit >= 4:
            print("game over")
            done = True
        sprite_group.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Sort of. Check my revision of the question

Comment: I like the output so far, but another thing I need implemented is to have the the program end if the color change becomes 10 or in this case if the ball goes over the blue (so a value of 4 since 3 = blue).

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you very much. This has been very helpful and informative.